# mongoDB service on ubuntu not repairing

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have an AWS ubuntu instance where I upgraded a) ubuntu version (to 16.04.2 from 16.04) and b) mongoDB version (to 3.4.3 from 3.2). However, when I did so, mongoDB unlinked to all my databases.

I was able to copy the database files to `/data/db/`, use `sudo mongod --repair` and in the `mongo` shell, access all the databases.

However, the **service** version of mongoDB, run when I execute `sudo service start mongod` is still using the original `/var/lib/mongodb/` (where the data still exists). When I try to repair from within the shell using `db.repairDatabase()`, I get only `{ "ok" : 1 }` but no added databases. I need to have the service mongod running so clients can access it.

Here is a readout of what the service mongod outputs:

```
> db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts")
{
"argv" : [
    "/usr/bin/mongod",
    "--quiet",
    "--config",
    "/etc/mongod.conf"
],
"parsed" : {
    "config" : "/etc/mongod.conf",
    "net" : {
        "bindIp" : "127.0.0.1",
        "port" : 27017
    },
    "storage" : {
        "dbPath" : "/var/lib/mongodb",
        "journal" : {
            "enabled" : true
        }
    },
    "systemLog" : {
        "destination" : "file",
        "logAppend" : true,
        "path" : "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log",
        "quiet" : true
    }
},
"ok" : 1
}
> db.repairDatabase()
{ "ok" : 1 }
> show databases
admin  0.000GB
local  0.000GB
```

How can I repair the service mongod databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I could use `mongodump --archive={path}` and dump to an archive from the local database that was working. Then I turned on the service and used `mongorestore --archive={path}`, which loaded everything to the correct database. It is functional again.